# Powershell - Repleace everything between "()"

Tags: powershell

I'm very new to PowerShell and are totally stuck with some replacement I'd love to make to a file.

I got a file that looks like this

```
Apple (Red)
Pear
Pineapple (Yellow)
Orange
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
Apple
Pear
Pineapple
Orange
```

I hope someone can help me out :)!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should the trailing space be removed as well? e.g. does ```Apple (Red)``` become ```Apple``` (5 chars) or ```Apple ``` (6 chars)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`replace` operator in PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#replacement-with-regular-expressions) to replace the pattern `"\(.*?\)"` with empty string. The syntax for `-replace` operator would be

```
<input> -replace <regular-expression>, <substitute>
```

So you can update your code with `-replace` operator like this,

```
$string = @'
Apple (Red)
Pear
Pineapple (Yellow)
Orange
'@

$replacedString = $string -replace "\(.*?\)", ""
Write-Host $replacedString
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Abdul :)!
If I got my file in a variable fx $File, how would I then be able to perform the regular expression? 

I tried Get-Content $file -replace "\(.*?\)", "" without luck.

Comment: Did you tried `(Get-Content $file) -replace "(.*?)", ""` Note that `-replace` is not an argument to `Get-Content`

Comment: Thank you (Get-Content $file) -replace "\(.*?\)", "" did the trick. Also I know think I understand how it works. Maybe one day I can help someone else out :)!